# Find Same Array and If condition have same I Will Update an Array Array on Vue Js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

so guys i have 3 array like these

**First Array**

```
"questions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "body": "Offers full service",
      "question_category_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "body": "Has required personnel",
      "question_category_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "body": "Has required facilities",
      "question_category_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "body": "Has required management philoshophy",
      "question_category_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "body": "Has a low personnel turnover",
      "question_category_id": 1
    }
  ]
```

**Second Array** call `scoreValue`

```
[
  {
    scorable_id: 1
    score: 9
  },
  {
    scorable_id: 2
    score: 9
  },
  {
    scorable_id: 3
    score: 9
  },
  {
    scorable_id: 4
    score: 9
  },
  {
    scorable_id: 5
    score: 9
  }
]
```

In essence, I want to find the same `question.id` as the array in the second array and then if it same i want to change my `score` value on the second array, i've tried like these

```
let questions_id = this.score.attributes.questions
  .filter(question => question.question_category_id == question_id)
  .map(question => {return question.id})
```

it got result like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

then i filter again like this

```
this.scoreValue.filter(values => values.scorable_id = questions_id).map(values => values.score = value)
```

maybe this code is wrong, i just want to change `this.scoreValue` `score` if have same `scorable_id` as `question` id

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do. How does the second array relate to the first?

Comment: Hi @Nick, I want to compare the question array (id) with the second array which contain id like on my image

Comment: The array in the image appears to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, so how does that affect the filtering of the first array?

Comment: @Nick Array on image is result from mapping `this.scoreValue`

Comment: Maybe someone else can come along to help, I still don't understand what you're trying to do!

Comment: Hi @Nick `let questions_id` is mapping filtering question and then mapping

Comment: what is 'question_id' in your filter function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by my frind @rizkymey

```
this.scoreValue.filter(question => questions_id.includes(question.scorable_id)).map(q => q.score = value)
```